# How to join two tables and aggregate data from second table using pandas and export it into json

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas, dictionary

I have two tables in database, which contain the following data:

```
 Descriptions                      Translations

| DescId | Description |          | DescId | Translation | Language |      
| 1      | hello       |          | 1      | hallo       | DE       |
| 2      | apple       |          | 1      | cześć       | PL       |
                                  | 1      | bonjour     | FR       |
                                  | 2      | apfel       | DE       |
                                  | 2      | jabłko      | PL       |
                                  | 2      | pomme       | FR       |
```

I want to achieve a json like that:

```
[
    {
        "desc": "Hello",
        "translations": [
            {
                "tran": "Hallo",
                "lang": "DE"
            },
            {
                "tran": "Cześć",
                "lang": "PL"
            },
            {
                "tran": "Bonjour",
                "lang": "FR"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "desc": "Apple",
        "translations": [
            {
                "tran": "Apfel",
                "lang": "DE"
            },
            {
                "tran": "Jabłko",
                "lang": "PL"
            },
            {
                "tran": "Pomme",
                "lang": "FR"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I was thinking to use pandas framework - merge two dataframes on DescId and then easily export it into dict/json. Is is possible to merge Translations on DescId and aggregate all columns into list of dicts?

Maybe there is a better way to create nested json by joining those two tables?